# unrecognized selector sent to instance [CustomAnnotation setTitle]

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to set custom annotation title value but I got the crash report.crash report is:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomAnnotation setTitle:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    MKMapRect mapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
    MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mapRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mapRect));
    MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mapRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mapRect));

    CGFloat meters = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint);

    if (meters > 15000)
        return;

    // if we have some backlogged requests, let's just get rid of them

    [self.searchQueue cancelAllOperations];

    // issue new MKLoadSearch

    [self.searchQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        __block BOOL done = NO;

        MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"theater";
        request.region = mapView.region;

        MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];



            [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

                for (CustomAnnotation *annotation in mapView.annotations)
                {
                    // if we don't need this one, don't add it, just return, and we'll check the next one

                    annotation.title;

                    NSLog(@"%@",annotation.title);

                    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
                        if (item.placemark.coordinate.latitude == annotation.coordinate.latitude &&
                            item.placemark.coordinate.longitude == annotation.coordinate.longitude)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                }


                NSLog(@"%f",item.placemark.coordinate.latitude);

                NSLog(@"%f",item.placemark.coordinate.longitude);
                // otherwise add it


                CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];

                CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.33554 longitude:-121.885209];

                CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:item.placemark.coordinate.latitude longitude:item.placemark.coordinate.longitude];

                CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
                NSLog(@"%f",distance);

                annotation.title=item.title;     --> i get crash report in this line
                NSLog(@"%@",annotation.title);
                annotation.phone = item.phoneNumber;
                annotation.subtitlee = item.placemark.addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                [annotations addObject:annotation];

                NSLog(@"%@",annotations);

                //[self.mapView addAnnotations:annotation.name];
            }];




            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                //CustomAnnotation

                [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
            }];

            done = YES;
        }];

        while (!done)
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                     beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }];


}
```

///////////////////////////////////

thank you...

```
enter code here



#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CustomAnnotation : MKPlacemark
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitlee;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger index;
enter code here
```

@end

Comment: Please the code where you init `annotation `.

Comment: did your annotation Class has a property named title?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Please paste the significant part of your code so anyone could reproduce your error.

Comment: customannotation.h:

 NSString *title;
 NSString *subtitle;
NSString *phone;

Comment: i updated my question.. pls help...

Comment: Why do you keep calling `annotation.title` without using it?

Comment: please update your question with the full content of CustomAnnotation.h

Comment: @Arc676   annotation.title=item.title;

Comment: Please show us the full content of CustomAnnotation.h

Answer (score 0):

Is your CustomAnnotation class inherit from MKAnnotation ? 
MKAnnotation defined

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `CustomAnnotation` is a subclass of `MKPlacemark`, which conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. The `MKAnnotation` protocol has got a property `title`.

So you are actually inheriting this property from the MKAnnotation protocol, but this is not what you want. Just rename your `title` property to e.g. `customAnnotationTitle` and you should be fine.